# SQL update with aggregate in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to set the date field for column date to let's say '10/11/2012' in table 1 when the sum of all amounts table 2 related to that id (via fk_id) = 0. Here's what I mean:

FROM:

table 1

```
    id    date
    1     10/11/2011
    2      
    3     10/12/2011
```

table 2

```
    fk_id    amount
    1     200
    2     0
    2     0
    3     100
```

TO:

table 1

```
    id    date
    1     10/11/2011
    2     10/11/2012
    3     10/12/2011
```

table 2

```
    fk_id    amount
    1     200
    2     0
    2     0
    3     100
```

This is what I have currently:

```
update table1
set date = '10/11/2012
FROM table1 inner join table 2 on table1.id = table2.fk_id
HAVING sum(table2.amount) = 0
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: why is `2  :   10/11/2012` after the update in table1

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - because the sum of `amount` fot the value `2` on `table 2` is zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 
SET date = '10/11/2012' 
FROM table1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT FK_ID FROM table2 GROUP BY FK_ID HAVING SUM(Amount)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE T1
SET [date] = '20121011'
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT fk_id, SUM(amount) Amount
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY fk_id
            HAVING SUM(amount) = 0) T2
ON T1.id = T2.fk_id
```